# Can't record game with a supported video card

Tags: pc, recording, windows-10

I have an AMD Radeon HD 7400 M GPU in my laptop, but the Gamebar says my PC doesn't meet the hardware requirements. My guess is that it only recognizes my integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000, which is not supported. I've downloaded the most recent drivers for both of the GPUs, but the recording still doesn't work.

Comment: @Mego because all motherboards come with some sort of integrated card? Pretty standard stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the proper GPU drivers installed for your machine then i do these steps:

1. Open the Catalyst Control Centre.
2. Click “Power” and select “Switchable Graphics.”
3. Choose an application from the list or browse and select an
       application and assign the appropriate GPU.

Comment: The gamebar's response is the same.

Comment: There are a lot of things you need to check, watch this video it might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCh9Eob0mNY :)

Comment: I checked them, but the problem is still unsolved